# Macro troubleshoot

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA programming and I have come across a debug error for a macro we use at work. the macro was written by another colleague who has no left the company. I will explain what happens originally the macro ran on windows 7 Microsoft 0ffice 2010 with no faults no we have migrated to windows 10  Microsoft Excel office 365 I get "run time error '5'" invalid procedure when I debug it is failing at the below code

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

is it because excel is referenced differently in 365 any assistance would be greatly appreciated

thank you Chris

Comment: The variable must have changed from `"Microsoft Excel"` to ? Try: `AppActivate Application.Caption`. On my version (Excel 2019), it works. Basically the newer versions should start with the workbook name. So standard would be: `Map1 - Excel`. Not sure about O365 though.

Comment: Ok thanks am I allowed to paste all the code to see if someone can spot why it fails in windows 10 365